# How to update all the columns in current table if some records are missing?

Tags: sql

I need to update my Product table. I need to add all the products which are not in
Product table by comparing the Catalogue table. My tables are as;

```
Product table
ProductID ProductName Quantity
1.        A.          3
2.        B.          2
3.        C.          3
Catalogue table
CatelogueID ProductID ProductName Quantity
1.          3.        C.          3
2.          4.        D.          1
3.          1.        A.          3
4.          6.        F.          5
5.          2.        B.          1
6.          5.        E.          0
```

Comment: And how is one meant to know what values to populate in `ProductName` and `Quantity` based purely on `Catalogue`?

Comment: Sorry, I will update the table. I'm new to SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the new row values ​​to insert into the `product` table, you need to get all the rows from the `catalogue` table, each product of which does not exist in the `product` table.

And yout query would be like this

```
INSERT INTO product  
SELECT productid, productname, quantity 
FROM catalogue c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM product p WHERE p.productid = c.productid
);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e92db537c9723aa6c6db8a926a5e2e5f)

Comment: Many thanks , its working on my real data